# How can I change elements inside and array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I get the `"e"` elements inside of "arr" to be replaced by `change0`?

The `arr` array will be an input by the user and I need to change it there is no way to predict which element will be `"e"`.

```
var arr = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "e", "j", "e"];

var change0 = 2

var change1 = 1

document.write(arr);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `map()` method and this will return new updated array and save original.

```js
var arr = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "e", "j", "e"];
var change0 = 2;

var result = arr.map(e => e == 'e' ? change0 : e);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `join` and `split` methods.

```js
var replace="change0";
var arr = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "e", "j", "e"];
console.log(arr.join().split('e').join(replace).split(','));
```

Comment: your result is a string. with joining, you lose the type of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Run a loop for getting index of element "e" and then repeat until there are more elements left:

```js
var arr = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "e", "j", "e"];

while (arr.indexOf("e") > 0){
    var index = arr.indexOf("e");
    arr[index] = "change0";
}
document.write(arr);
```

Comment: What a waste! Calling `indexOf` twice per replacement! And calling it from the start each time!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and search for all elements and change then with the given value.

```js
var array = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "e", "j", "e"],
    search = "e",
    change = 2,
    p = array.indexOf(search);
    
while (p !== -1) {
    array[p] = change;
    p = array.indexOf(search, p + 1);
}

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use indexOf to determine the index of the element in an array. So basically, you can just go like this:

```
arr[arr.indexOf('e')] = change0;
```

It will not work if you have multiple element that have the values of 'e'. It will only change the first one so you have to put it through a loop. Or use map.

Answer (score 1):

Using `forEach`:

```js
var arr = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "e", "j", "e"];

var change = "changed";

arr.forEach(function(v, i) {
  if(v === "e")
    arr[i] = change;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: gosh I love you so much, thanks for the quick answer

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert to string
2. Replace 'e'
3. Convert back to array

```js
var arr = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "e", "j", "e"];

console.log((((arr.toString()).replace(/e/g,"changed"))).split(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to handle more than one letter, it’s best to prepare encoder/decoder (a function or an array) in advance. Then your job becomes as simple as:

```
output = input.map(val => encoder[val] || val);
```

The `|| val` part is for values not handled by the encoder.

#### Working example

In this example, we use `split("")` to convert string to array and `join("")` to do the opposite.

```js
PrepareCodec:
    var Latin    = "abcdefghijklmnoprstuvyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVYZ";
    var Cyrillic = "абцдефгхийклмнопрстувызАБЦДЕФГХИЙКЛМНОПРСТУВЫЗ";
    var encoder = {}, decoder = {};
    for (let i in Latin)    encoder[Latin[i]] = Cyrillic[i];
    for (let i in Cyrillic) decoder[Cyrillic[i]] = Latin[i];

EncryptionTest:
    var src = prompt("Enter text to encrypt:", "Hello, world!");
    var enc = src.split("").map(val => encoder[val] || val).join("");
DecryptionTest:
    enc = prompt("Enter text to decrypt:", enc);
    var dec = enc.split("").map(val => decoder[val] || val).join("");
FinalResult:
    prompt("Decrypted text:", dec);
```